# access to object in async function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a beginner in node.js

So, 
I used this to

```
  var toFix = {
    'renault': 'Renault',
    'renault ': 'Renault',
    'RENAULT ': 'Renault',
    'RENAULT': 'Renault',
};

  async.forEachOfSeries(toFix, function(to, from, cb){
    Car.update({make:from }, {$set: {make: to}}, {multi: true},cb)
  }, done);
```

and it worked for my table car.

but when I want to use the same code in an other table, where car is an object in a table, It doesn't work, for exemple:

```
async.forEachOfSeries(toFix, function(to, from, cb){
        Ticket.update({car.make:from }, {$set: {car.make: to}}, {multi: true},cb)
      }, done);
```

it can't accept car.make  .
so how should I access to my object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async.forEachOfSeries(toFix, function(to, from, cb){
    Ticket.update({'car.make':from }, {$set: {'car.make': to}}, {multi: true},cb)
  }, done);
```

Change car.make to 'car.make'